# React Native InApp Browser - Selecting a file (File Explorer) for uploading make InApp browser to close only with Google Chrome

Tags: android, react-native, expo, inappbrowser

I am currently working on a project on Android using the Expo client for react native. When I use expo-web-browser or react-native-inappbrowser-reborn and call for example WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://fr.imgbb.com/"), it will open the website correctly. When I try to upload a file, it opens the file explorer correctly but when I select an image or other files, it closes the InApp Browser and redirect me to the App.

This problem occurs only if the InApp Browser is powered by Google. When I use for example the browser Samsung Internet, the problem doesn't occur.

Am I missing something ?

PS: My app is already detached from expo

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I had to put the option like this WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://fr.imgbb.com/", {showInRecents : true})